# Ruby on Rails - Modify macro to pass in a computed value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macros

I have a macro that is used to cache assertion values. I didn't write this concern but would like to modify it to use dynamic values in the block, rather than a static min/max.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Provides a lightweight model-level DSL for defining conditions with
# Redis-backed configurable criteria.
#
# Example:
#
# class User
#   include CriteriaCacheConcern
#
#   # Each criterion has a default value (second argument) that can be overridden by
#   # a cached value. When evaluating criteria, we read first from cache (Redis) and
#   # fall back on the default value if no cached value is present. Values are cached
#   # under a key of this composition: 'model_class-condition-attribute'; e.g.,
#   # 'user-auto_reject-application-score'
#
#   criteria_cache :auto_reject do
#     range :application-score, [0, 20]
#     range :user_age,          [0, 18]
#   end
# end
#
# # Set Redis-backed min/max
# User.auto_reject_post_application.applicant_percentile_score.configure(min: 1, max: 21)
#
# # Are all criteria satisfiable for the user for this condition?
# user.auto_reject_post_application?

module CriteriaCacheConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.criteria_caches
      @criteria_caches || []
    end

    def self.criteria_cache(condition, &block)
      criteria_cache = CriteriaCache.new(condition, name).tap { |cc| cc.instance_eval(&block) }

      # Access the criteria cache object from the class
      #
      # Example:
      # User.auto_reject_post_application
      singleton_class.send(:define_method, condition) do
        criteria_cache
      end

      # Does the model meet the criteria?
      #
      # Example:
      # user.auto_reject_post_application?
      define_method("#{condition}?") do
        criteria_cache.meets_criteria?(self)
      end

      @criteria_caches ||= []
      @criteria_caches << criteria_cache
    end
  end

  class ConfigurableCriterion
    attr_reader :condition, :model_class, :attribute, :default_value

    def initialize(condition, model_class, attribute, default_value)
      @condition = condition
      @model_class = model_class
      @attribute = attribute
      @default_value = default_value
    end

    def value
      RedisHelper.cached_value(cache_key) || default_value
    end

    def configure(_params)
      raise NotImplementedError, 'ConfigurableCriterion subclass must implement #configure'
    end

    def meets_criterion?(_model)
      raise NotImplementedError, 'ConfigurableCriterion subclass must implement #meets_criterion?'
    end

    private

    def cache_key
      "#{model_class.underscore}-#{condition}-#{attribute}"
    end
  end

  # ConfigurableCriterion subclasses
  # --------------------------------
  #
  # All ConfigurableCriterion subclasses should implement the following interface:
  #
  # class ConfigurableCriterionSubclass < ConfigurableCriterion
  #   # Does the model satisfy the criterion?
  #   def meets_criterion?(model)
  #   end
  #
  #   # Update cached values
  #   def configure(params)
  #   end
  # end

  class Range < ConfigurableCriterion
    def min
      value.min
    end

    def max
      value.max
    end

    def meets_criterion?(model)
      (min..max).cover?(model.send(attribute))
    end

    def configure(params)
      min = params.fetch(:min) { default_value.min }.to_i
      max = params.fetch(:max) { default_value.max }.to_i
      raise ArgumentError, 'Maximum must be larger than minimum' if max <= min

      RedisHelper.cache_value(cache_key, [min, max])
    end
  end

  # ---------------------------------

  class CriteriaCache
    attr_reader :condition, :model_class, :criteria

    def initialize(condition, model_class)
      @condition = condition
      @model_class = model_class
      @criteria = []
    end

    # Define method for each configurable criterion type that adds
    # criterion object to @criteria collection
    #
    # Example of resultant method:
    # criteria_cache.range(attribute, default_value)
    ConfigurableCriterion.descendants.each do |klass|
      define_method(klass.name.demodulize.underscore) do |attribute, default_value|
        criterion = klass.new(condition, model_class, attribute, default_value)

        @criteria << criterion

        # Return configurable criterion object
        #
        # Example:
        # User.auto_reject_post_application.applicant_percentile_score
        define_singleton_method(criterion.attribute) do
          criterion
        end
      end
    end

    def meets_criteria?(model)
      @criteria.all? { |c| c.meets_criterion?(model) }
    end
  end
end
```

and is used as so

```
criteria_cache :auto_assign_user do
  range :user_score, [80 , 100]
end
```

I would like to alter the macro to be able to set the range based on a computed value. For example, the `User` model has a method `lowest_score_to_auto_assign` that would calculate a unique lower bound range used in the `auto_assign_user` block.

I'm not familiar enough to know how I might pass that into the `CriteriaCacheConcern`

Comment: When you say the "...the `User` model has a method `lowest_score_to_auto_assign`" do you mean an instance method e.e. `user.lowest_score_to_auto_assign` or a class instance method e.g. `User.lowest_score_to_auto_assign`. If the former, it does not appear you can based on the current implementation. if the later then `range :user_score,  [User.lowest_score_to_auto_assign , 100]` should work

Comment: @engineersmnky instance method. `lowest_score_to_auto_assign` would be unique to each user.

Comment: I know what a macro is in C, what is a "macro" in Ruby?